# how to find string from array and assign it to a string in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arrays, string

i have to Design an interface that reads a string and finds the very first occurrence of any one character out of (m , n and t  alphabet) in a given string

the output should be like this

Input : computer
Output : The first character from the list is  “m” occurred at position 3 in “Computer”. It is the 3rd of 8 characters in the word

my code:

```
string a = TextBox1.Text;
string result = "";
int ss = a.Length;
string[] m = {"t","n","m"};
int b;

//search for m or n or t and assign it to string result

b = a.IndexOf (result) + 1;
string str = a.Substring(b-1,1);

Label2.Text = "The first character from the list is " + str +
     " occurred at position " + b.ToString() + " in "+ a +".
     it is the "+ b.ToString() + "rd of " + ss.ToString() +
     " characters in the word.";
```

how i can search for m or n or t and assign it to string result?!!!

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: @MokshShah how to search for m or n or t and assign it to string result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Try this:-

```
             string a = "Computer";
        string result = "";
        int ss = a.Length;
        string[] m = { "t", "n", "m" };
        int b=0;
        string str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < ss;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]=='t' || a[i]=='n' || a[i]=='m')
            {
                b = i+1;
                str = a[i].ToString();

                break;
            }
        }
      Label2.Text = "The first character from the list is " + str +
            " occurred at position " + b.ToString() + " in " + a + ". it is the " + b.ToString() +
            "rd of " + ss.ToString() + " characters in the word.";
```

Comment: please mark it as answer if you find it useful....

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the for loop to get what you want. You will loop through your array and if found just print it on the label and break the label if not found just continue with the loop.

```
string a = TextBox1.Text;
int ss = a.Length;
string[] m = {"t","n","m"};
for(int i=0;i<m.Length;i++)
{
   int b = a.IndexOf (m[i]);
   if(b==-1)
      continue ; // IF not found instring continue with next character
   else
    {
      string str = a.Substring(b,1);
      Label2.Text = "The first character from the list is " + str+ " occurred at position " + (++b).ToString() + " in "+ a +". it is the "+ (++b).ToString() +
    "rd of " + ss.ToString() + " characters in the word.";
      break; // If character found break out of loop 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, create an extension method that can find all the index of character from the given string and return list of indexes.
then loop through all the characters of your list and print its indexes.

try bellow code

```
string a = "Computert" ;

        int ss = a.Length;
        string[] m = {"t","n","m"};

        foreach(var charactersToFind in m)
        {
            var indexes = a.AllIndexesOf(charactersToFind);
             Label2.Text += "The first character from the list is '" + charactersToFind + "' occurred at position " + string.Join(",", indexes.ToArray()) + " in "+ a +".";
        }
```

Here is your extension method.

```
public static class extensions
{

    public static List<int> AllIndexesOf(this string str, string value) {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            throw new ArgumentException("the string to find may not be empty", "value");
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
        for (int index = 0;; index += value.Length) {
            index = str.IndexOf(value, index);
            if (index == -1)
                return indexes;
            indexes.Add(index);
        }
     }
}
```

Have a look at this simple console application 
[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9uhLL5)

Comment: It's good code but I think OP is just getting started with basic loops so don't you think the extension methods are far fetched a bit complicated for him. Plus you didn't even provide any explanation.

Comment: I don't think its that much complicated, or OP may ask for more clarification. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this:

```
           string a = textBox1.Text;
           string[] m = { "t", "n", "m" };
            int[] firstPositions = { -1, -1, -1 };

            //search for m or n or t and assign it to string result
            for (int i = 0; i < m.Length; i++)
            {
               firstPositions[i]= a.IndexOf(m[i]);
            }

            int min =a.Length;
            int firstPos = -1;
            for(int i=0;i<firstPositions.Length;i++)
            {
                if (firstPositions[i] < min && firstPositions[i] != -1)
                {
                    min = firstPositions[i];
                    firstPos = i;
                }
            }

             if(firstPos!=-1)

            label1.Text = "The first character from the list is " + m[firstPos] +
                " occurred at position " + (a.IndexOf(m[firstPos])+1) + " in " + a + ". it is the " + (a.IndexOf(m[firstPos])+1) +
                "rd of " + a.Length + " characters in the word.";
```